# How to make sure an item already pulled from mysql doesn't get pulled again

Tags: php, mysql, tags, foreach

I'm making a related stories section which uses the tags in a post to go through and find other stories with similar tags.

I want to make sure that I'm not pulling the same story multiple times if it shares more than one tag with another post.

So it's basically

```
foreach($tags as $t) {

  $getStories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$t%' LIMIT 2");

  while($related = mysql_fetch_array($getStories)) {
    echo $related['title'];
  }
```

So I pull 2 related stories based on the first tag, now, when it goes around through next loop for the second tag, how can I make sure that a story pulled the last time doesn't get picked the second or third time. I do have a unique ID just called 'id', just not sure what to do with it in this situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is fetch all related articles at once:

```
$tagsClause = '';
foreach ($tags as $t) {
    $tagsClause .= " OR tags LIKE '%$t%'";
}
$tagsClause = substr($tagsClause, 4); // Remove first ' OR '

$getStories = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE ' . $tagsClause);
while($related = mysql_fetch_array($getStories)) {
    echo $related['title'];
}
```

**However**, this does not account for your use of `LIMIT`.

**EDIT**
Apparently this did not pose a problem, cf. comments.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is working out as expected. I just threw a "LIMIT 5" at the end of the mysql_query and it looks like it's working just as I'd like.

Comment: @scatteredbomb Great. This approach would not have been suited if you were doing something along the lines of "find at most two related articles for each tag but don't fetch the same article twice," which, apparently, you're *not* doing :)

Comment: Yeah, the only point for the limit 2 in the original query was because I couldn't figure out a way to only limit it to a total of 5 results dependent on the number of tags. This way way works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use UNIQUE.

```
SELECT UNIQUE(post_id), [other stuff] FROM posts WHERE [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can make an array containing the ids you have selected, when you process a tag, check the id is not in the selected array, but it's not efficient.

just like this:

```
$ids = array();
foreach($tags as $t) {
  $getStories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `tags` = '$t' LIMIT 2");

  //here to check and add id to array ids
  while($related = mysql_fetch_array($getStories)) {
    echo $related['title'];
  }
}
```